# How to connect Pgadmin3 to a database on Virtualbox machine?

Tags: postgresql, virtual-machine, virtualbox, postgresql-9.1, pgadmin

I have an Ubuntu Server with Postgresql server on Virtualbox machine (which runs on local machine), and Pgadmin3 on local machine.
Now how can I connect with Pgadmin3 to a database on Virtualbox? I am getting

```
"Server doesn't listen"
```

Postgres is actually running inside Virtualbox.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found this out. To make it work, i did:

1) Edited file /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf , uncommented and edited one line to contain:

```
listen_addresses = '10.10.4.14,localhost'
```

Where 10.10.4.14 is address used to access server on virtualbox.

2) Edited file /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf , added one line at the end:

```
host     all             all             10.10.4.14/24           md5
```

Note file path in your case might be different if your Postgres version is not the same as mine, or another linux distribution might place those files in other locations.

Comment: `listen_addresses = '*'` is typically sufficient

Comment: @CraigRinger, then what would this option exist for?

Comment: Sometimes you have a server with multiple network interfaces and you only want a PostgreSQL instance to listen on one of them. It might be for security (listen on internal interface but not DMZ / Internet) or it might be so you can run different PostgreSQL servers on the same port bound to different IP addresses. That sort of thing. It's not commonly required.